# jQuery add and remove inputs

Tags: jquery, dynamic, addition, element

I need to modify the following code that allows me to use them for separate iterations on the same page. The button codes below is the `+` and `-` icons [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0tC33MqRSdsZWIzM2IxNTEtMGUxMC00MmEzLTgwNzgtY2IzYTI2ZjkyZDM3&hl=en). At the moment, they conflict and i still need to add & remove whole iteration box.

Here's my script codes:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var count = $('.clonedIteration').length;
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
    // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
    //add parent so that the adding is only specific to those within the class
    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
    // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
    newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + count);
    //prepend table code
    $('#input' + num).append('<tr><td colspan="2"><label>');
    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
    //prepend table code
    $('#input' + newNum).append('</label></td></tr>');
    // enable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', '');
    // business rule: you can only add XXX times
    if (newNum == 5) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');


    return false
});

$('#btnDel').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    $('#input' + num).remove(); // remove the last element
    // enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', '');
    // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
    if (num - 1 == 1)

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    return false
});

$('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LetZh/1/
Your code is a bit more complex. I didn't implement all what you have.

**Edit**

http://jsfiddle.net/LetZh/2/ I brought some corrections to the js code.

Comment: Hey cronos, you blew my mind with this! This is simply amazing! Thanks!

Comment: Just to check with you also, how do you ensure at least one textbox per iteration and at least 2 iterations to work with? Meaning if i cannot delete iteration if i have 2 iterations and i cannot delete textbox if i have just one lef.